# Calculate number with leading zeros

Tags: mysql

I need to make this procedure work with data that is stored as VARCHAR with some rows that are stored with leading zeros

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getfreenum
             (IN num integer,
              IN maxval integer)
BEGIN
  SELECT CASE
       WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                               FROM artikli t2
                               WHERE t2.sifra = num * power(10, maxval - floor(log10(num)) - 1)) THEN
         num * power(10, maxval - floor(log10(num)) - 1)
       ELSE
         min(t1.sifra) + 1
     END sifra
     FROM artikli t1
     WHERE floor(log10(num)) < maxval
           AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                              FROM artikli t2
                              WHERE sifra = num * power(10, maxval - floor(log10(num)) - 1))
           AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                  FROM artikli t2
                                  WHERE t2.sifra = t1.sifra + 1)
           AND t1.sifra >= num * power(10, maxval - floor(log10(num)) - 1) - 1
           AND t1.sifra < num * power(10, maxval - floor(log10(num)) - 1) + power(10, maxval - floor(log10(num)) - 1) - 1;
END;
```

This is [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hiJGYtNhJAp72qH9RXVJc7/7)
Query #1 should return 00004

Comment: Don't you need to quote those numeric values (in the fiddle) so they're stored as strings rather than treated as integers?

Comment: Padding is often accomplished as something like : `right(5, '0000' + cast(n as int))`. MySQL may have other formatting functions that I'm not aware of too.

Comment: @shawnt00 Indeed, MySQL padding is: LPAD(string, length, lpad_string) but i am still not sure how to implement it here

Comment: In [your db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hiJGYtNhJAp72qH9RXVJc7/7), query#1 returns NULL, while you expect 00004 ? It is unclear what you want to be fixed in the procedure...

Comment: @GMB I think you answered your question.